# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I like to run a servlet on a tomcat server but it gives the error as above.Also when i put ajax request on the servlet it did  not working through  index.jsp.Please help me friends.
also explain briefly because I am at the starting level of servlet.

```
       import java.sql.Connection;  
    java.sql.DriverManager;  
  import java.sql.ResultSet;  
   import java.sql.Statement;    
  import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MySQLAccess  extends HttpServlet
 {  

    public void getRows(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws       IOException, ServletException
{
    String a="";
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    try 
       {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sankar?" + "user=root");  
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  



        ResultSet resultSet = statement   
                .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sankar.datas");  
       a=resultSet.getString("name");

        }  

     catch (Exception e) 
       {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
       } 

    out.println(a);  
}                           
}
```

Comment: you dont have doGet or doPost methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to accept the `GET` request, you need to override the `doGet` method in your `MySQLAccess` servlet class. Considering the code, you may just have to replace the name of your `getRows` method to `doGet`. From [javadocs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

> HttpServlet class provides an abstract class to be subclassed to
>   create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site. A subclass of
>   HttpServlet must override at least one method, usually one of these:
>
> - doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
> - doPost, for HTTP POST requests
> - doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
> - doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests

Answer (score 1):

You need the `doGet`-Method like so:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // your code
}
```

This method is called from the server (tomcat container more specifically) when a `GET` request is sent to the servlet.

If you wish to use `POST` you need to implement the `doPost(...)`method, btw.